# Node runs two files when I tell it to run one

Tags: node.js

I'm just beginning to learn Node, but I've run into a weird error. Whenever I tell node to run a file, it runs two files instead of only the one I told it to run.

I have a file called "app.js" and another one called "logger.js". This is "app.js":

```
function helloworld(msg) {
     console.log(msg)
}
console.log("Hello world! This is app.js")

module.exports.myhelloworldfunction = helloworld
```

And this is "logger.js":

```
const appjs = require("./app")
appjs.myhelloworldfunction("This is a message. ")
```

Whenever I do "node logger.js" in my terminal, I get this output:

```
Hello world!
This is a message.
```

When all I should be getting is:

```
This is a message
```

As I said, I'm an absolute beginner, so I assume I'm making a silly mistake here, but does anyone know why this happens and how I can fix it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you import a file, its content will be executed.

In your case, a function called `helloworld` would be defined, that log statement executed and the function you created exported (ie made accessible to the outside).

So just remove the `log` statement, or if you just want it to be printed when the file is executed instead of imported, you can use something like this:

```
if (require.main === module) {
    console.log("I'm being executed")
} else {
    console.log("I'm being imported")
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Marked as solution.